# The project is not a Gradle-based project after syncing

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

I'm facing an error with Android Studio, after pressing the sync button in the `build.gradle` file, and it just says that

> The project 'ProjectName' is not a Gradle-based project

With no further information to consider, so what should I do in such condition?

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure , but i think the problem is related to your IDE .

the settings.gradle file and bulid.gradle file are not in the IDE project directory, they are in that blacked-out subfolder under .idea and .gradle.

the `allprojects` and `buildscript` should not be in /subDirectory/build.gradle but /build.gradle .

try opening the IDE again properly .

Comment: And how di I do that if so, dear George? because, I think they are in the right place.

Comment: maybe you can share screen shoot from your project explorer in IDE ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't provide a screen shot in the comment section

Comment: but you can edit the question and attach an image .

Answer (score 0):

Following those steps solved my issue:

1. Close Android Studio.
2. Navigate to your Flutter project's root directory and delete the `.idea` folder and any `*.iml` files.
3. Run `flutter clean`, and `flutter pub get` on your project root.
4. Reopen Android Studio.

It should be synced.
Enjoy!